# Is there a general algorithm to find a matrix $P$ such that $\exists _x(M.x=b\land x\geq 0)\iff P.b\geq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

CONTEXT: I am not a student or a mathematician, just an amateur looking for an algorithm.

---

> Given a full rank matrix $M$, is there a general algorithm to find a matrix $P$ such that:
>
> $$\exists _x(M.x=b\land x\geq 0)\iff P.b\geq 0$$

---

In my problem, the *b* is a vector of parameters of the problem -- I want to know the constraints on the parameters. For which values of *b* is there a solution to $M.x=b\land x\geq 0$?

Notice that the possible values of x form a convex polytope (possibly unbounded, but still convex). It is bounded by a set of planes, each which can be "moved" linearly in the direction of their norm by the parameters in *b*. This strongly suggests to me that the possible values of b are similarly linearly bounded. Is this true?

I *think* the minimum dimensions of $P$ are $(Nullity(M), Rows(M))$, is that right?

---

If $M$ is not full rank, then the full form of the problem is the following:

> Find $M_1$, $M_2$, $M_3$, $M_4$ such that $$(M.x = b \land x \geq 0) \iff (M_1.x = M_2.b\land M_3.b = 0 \land M_4.b\geq 0 \land x\geq 0)$$ and
> $$\exists _x(M.x=b\land x\geq 0)\iff (M_3.b = 0\land  M_4.b\geq 0)$$

For example, suppose $M$ is this matrix (which is not full rank):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $M_1$ is the reduced row echelon form (with zero rows removed):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$M_2$ is the "row reducing" and "zero-row-removing" matrix for M:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$M_3$ is this (does anyone know what this is called?):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & -2 & -3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

And the matrix I'm looking for, $M_4$, can be:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

but I think there is a smaller matrix that can do the job.

EDIT: Further work made me realize that you still need x >= 0 for the equivalence, and I added a short paragraph to help explain the problem.

EDIT: Added my intuition that the solution is linear.

Comment: M is given. We are looking for the constraints on b

Comment: What led you to believe that the constraints on $b$ will be non-strict linear inequalities? Do you have Mathematica?

Comment: Yes I have Mathematica

Comment: I assumed the constraints on b are non strict because the constraints on x are non-strict.

Comment: Then use function `reduce` to perform quantifier elimination. You will get a quantifier-free formula on the entries of $b$. Done.

Comment: Reduce experiences a combinatorial explosion on problems like these, and I am only using Mathematica to design and test the algorithm. I need to know the algorithm, not just the result of a single case.

Comment: Another way to ask my question: *how* does Mathematica eliminate a quantifier like this? What's Mathematica's algorithm?

Comment: The inequalities are linear, which is why I expect the solution to be linear.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The set the question is asking for is the image of a convex set $\{ x \mid x \ge 0 \}$ under a linear transformation $M$, so it should certainly be convex.  (And in fact, the argument will show the image set is a cone, i.e. it's closed under any linear combination with nonnegative coefficients.)

Comment: @CharlesGillingham I don't know if this is standard terminology - but I think if you called $M_3$ a "cokernel matrix" that would probably be likely to be understood.  i.e. $M_3$ is a matrix representing a cokernel morphism for $M$.  [At least, under the assumption that $M_3$ represents a surjective morphism, iff $M_3$ has full rank, iff $M_3$ has linearly independent rows.]

Comment: "cokernal matrix" ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give a procedure to eliminate a single existential in $\exists t, M \begin{bmatrix} x \\ t \end{bmatrix} = 0 \wedge N \begin{bmatrix} x \\ t \end{bmatrix} \ge 0$ (where $x$ represents a vector of the other variables) to be equivalent to an expression of the form $M' x = 0 \wedge N' x \ge 0$.  Then you should be able to apply this iteratively to eliminate the existentials in $\exists x_1 \cdots \exists x_n, M x = b \wedge x \ge 0$ to get it equivalent to an expression of the form $M' b = 0 \wedge N' b \ge 0$ (which is of course equivalent to $\begin{bmatrix} M' \\ -M' \\ N' \end{bmatrix} b \ge 0$, but you expressed interest in having $M'$ and $N'$ separately).

First, if the last column of $M$ contains any nonzero element, you can use this to solve for $t$ in terms of $x$ and substitute in.

Otherwise, you can drop the last column of $M$ to get $M'$; then $M \begin{bmatrix} x \\ t \end{bmatrix} = M' x$.  Now, for each row of $N$, if the last element is 0, it reduces to an inequality just in terms of $x$.  Otherwise, depending on the sign of this last element, you can express the inequality corresponding to that row as either $t \le \langle a, x \rangle$ or $t \ge \langle b, x \rangle$ for some vector $a$ or $b$.  Let us suppose you do this and get $N \begin{bmatrix} x \\ t \end{bmatrix} \ge 0$ equivalent to $N' x \ge 0 \wedge t \le \langle a_1, x \rangle \wedge \cdots \wedge t \le \langle a_r, x \rangle \wedge t \ge \langle b_1, x \rangle \wedge \cdots \wedge t \ge \langle b_s, x \rangle$.  Then the last part of this is equivalent to $\max(\langle b_1, x \rangle, \cdots, \langle b_s, x \rangle) \le t \le \min(\langle a_1, x \rangle, \cdots, \langle a_r, x \rangle)$, and such a $t$ exists if and only if $\max(\langle b_1, x \rangle, \cdots, \langle b_s, x \rangle) \le \min(\langle a_1, x \rangle, \cdots, \langle a_r, x \rangle)$.  But this is further equivalent to $\wedge_{j=1}^s \wedge_{i=1}^r \langle b_j, x \rangle \le \langle a_i, x \rangle \Leftrightarrow \wedge_{j=1}^s \wedge_{i=1}^r \langle a_i - b_j, x \rangle \ge 0$ and we have now reduced to the desired form.

---

To illustrate the algorithm, let me run it on a simpler case $M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$, so we want to eliminate the existentials in $\exists x_1 \exists x_2 \exists x_3, p$ where $p$ is the statement $$x_1 + x_2 = b_1 \wedge x_2 + x_3 = b_2 \wedge x_1 - x_3 = b_3 \wedge x_1 \ge 0 \wedge x_2 \ge 0 \wedge x_3 \ge 0.$$

Now by substitution $x_3 = -x_2 + b_2$, we get $\exists x_3, p$ is equivalent to $$x_1 + x_2 = b_1 \wedge x_1 + x_2 - b_2 = b_3 \wedge x_1 \ge 0 \wedge x_2 \ge 0 \wedge -x_2 + b_2 \ge 0.$$
Similarly, by substitution $x_2 = -x_1 + b_1$, we get $\exists x_2 \exists x_3, p$ is equivalent to
$$b_1 - b_2 = b_3 \wedge x_1 \ge 0 \wedge -x_1 + b_1 \ge 0 \wedge x_1 - b_1 + b_2 \ge 0.$$
This one now falls into the second case above: $\exists x_2 \exists x_3, p$ is equivalent to
$$b_1 - b_2 = b_3 \wedge x_1 \ge 0 \wedge x_1 \ge b_1 - b_2 \wedge x_1 \le b_1.$$
Therefore, $\exists x_1 \exists x_2 \exists x_3, p$ is equivalent to
$$b_1 - b_2 = b_3 \wedge b_1 \ge 0 \wedge b_1 \ge b_1 - b_2.$$
(So it's perhaps unfortunate that the example I chose ended up having a simple solution $b_1 - b_2 - b_3 = 0 \wedge b_1 \ge 0 \wedge b_2 \ge 0$; but hopefully, you should see the idea.)

---

As for the part with $M_1$ through $M_4$, I get the feeling that what you are looking for is to express $p$ in a "maximally triangularized" form.  It should be possible to do so in general; for instance, in the example above, we would get that $p$ is equivalent to
$$b_1 \ge 0 \wedge b_2 \ge 0 \wedge b_3 = b_1 - b_2 \wedge x_1 \ge 0 \wedge x_1 \ge b_1 - b_2 \wedge x_1 \le b_1 \wedge \\ x_2 = b_1 - x_1 \wedge x_3 = -b_1 + b_2 + x_1.$$
More generally, you should be able to find matrices $M_1$ through $M_4$ such that $Mx = b \wedge x \ge 0$ is equivalent to $M_1 b = 0 \wedge M_2 b \ge 0 \wedge M_3 \begin{bmatrix} b \\ x \end{bmatrix} = 0 \wedge M_4 \begin{bmatrix} b \\ x \end{bmatrix} \ge 0$, and furthermore $\exists x, Mx = b \wedge x \ge 0$ is equivalent to $M_1 b = 0 \wedge M_2 b \ge 0$.

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you.

Comment: My only disappointment is that we get a combinatorial explosion in the last couple of steps -- not sure how serious this will turn out to be at this point.